Take kronecker product of non-adjacent qubits
Suppose I have 4 qubits and I have the density matrix on qubits 1, 3 and I want to take the tensor product with the identity on the 2nd and 4th qubits for example. What is the fastest way to code this? I can think of writing a large swap operation but I wanted to see if there is a better way of implementing this.

Isn't this just done by reordering the Kronecker products? Then you would just have a 4x4 identity Kronecker with a 4x4 density matrix, which is just block diagonal with the blocks being the 4x4 density matrix, and the order of the product is 2413.

Yeah but how do you reorder the 16 x 16 in code easily? And how do you generalize the code?

I mean i can think to algorithmically do a bunch of swap gates until i swap the right ones but i wanted to see if there was a more efficient or easier way to do this.

You may want to specify what language you code in. In Mathematica, for example, your task would simply be accomplished by KroneckerProduct[rho1,IdentityMatrix[2],rho3,IdentityMatrix[2]]

In Python please
